# How to draw this P-V graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am stuck on drawing a P-V graph through latex. Could anybody help me code on this? [image]

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Some people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: You can try to understand this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298682/1952

Comment: I appreciate your helps!
@Ignasi I'll investigate on this. Do you know how I can draw the inverse proportional line from dot 3 to dot 1?

Comment: You can use something like `to[out=180, in=-90]` between point 3 name|coordinates and point 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly different version. I tried to emulate the slightly longer gap between `V1`and `V2`. So basically the arc is not a regular one, but it's like a section of an ellipse (whose center would be `T2`).

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    midar/.style 2 args={
        very thick,
        decoration={name=markings,
        mark=at position .55 with {\arrow{latex}},
        mark=at position 0 with {\fill circle (2pt);},
        mark=at position 1 with {\fill circle (2pt);}}
        ,postaction=decorate,
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \draw[-{Latex}] (0,0) -- (0,4.5) node[above right] {$p$};
    \draw[-{Latex}] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$V$};

    \draw[dashed] (0,4) node[left] {$p_{1}$} -| (2,0) node[below] {$V_{1}$};
    \draw[dashed] (0,2) node[left] {$p_{3}$} -| (4.5,0) node[below] {$V_{2}$};

\draw[midar] (2,4) node[above left]{1} node[above right]{$T_1$} -- 
    (4.5,4) node[above left]{2} node[above right]{$T_2$};   
\draw[midar] (4.5,4) -- (4.5,2) node[above right]{3} node[below right]{$T_1$};
\draw[midar] (4.5,2) arc (270:180:2.5 and 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not perfect, but should give you a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,newtxmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  > = latex,
  dot/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt},
  arrow inside/.style = {postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with \arrow{>}}}
  ]
  \draw[<->] (0,4.3) node[above right] {$p$} |- (4.3,0) node[right] {$V$};
  \draw[dashed] (0,4) node[left] {$p_1$} -- (4,4);
  \draw[dashed] (0,2) node[left] {$p_3$} -- (4,2);
  \draw[dashed] (4,0) node[below] {$V_2$} -- (4,4);
  \draw[dashed] (2,0) node[below] {$V_1$} -- (2,4);
  \node[dot,label={above:$1$},label={above right:$T_1$}] (@1) at (2,4) {};
  \node[dot,label={right:$2$},label={above right:$T_2$}] (@2) at (4,4) {};
  \node[dot,label={right:$3$},label={above right:$T_3$}] (@3) at (4,2) {};
  \draw[arrow inside] (@1) -- (@2);
  \draw[arrow inside] (@2) -- (@3);
  \draw[arrow inside] (@3) to[out=180,in=-90] (@1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]